# How to get clicked position of div element for progressbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, html5-video

I have a HTML5 Video panel in my app. I managed to make a progressbar which is working perfectly. But I also want to ability to change `currentTime` of the video by clicking to any position on progressbar.

How can I get current position as ratio using React? I searched progressbar components on google but it seems none of them give `value` of clicked position but just display.

Or simply, when user clicks on different position of the progressbar, I want to change/get value of progressbar to that position.

[image]

### Update:

I have updated demo and it seems progressbar gone crazy when click multiple times and it seems not close to the clicked position either.

[image]

**Demo**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-zudlbe?file=index.tsx

Comment: what about this `const x = (event.clientX / event.target.offsetWidth) * duration;`
`clientWidth` would work too I guess

Comment: Seems not works well. Sometimes, it works sometimes not. Especially If I click over green (progress) bar. I've updated the demo, added callback and state. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Seems link messed up. I've updated again.

Comment: what is the issue in there?

Comment: I've added a gif to the question. As you can see clicked position is not correct when multiple times clicked or even not so close to the clicked position.

Comment: `const x = (event.clientX * duration) / event.currentTarget.offsetWidth;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the whole component I tested it on.
Seems to work

```
const ProgressBar = ({ duration, progress }: ProgressProps) => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        // duration is the video duration. For example 152.
        // How can i catch the % (ratio) of clicked position of this progrssbar?
        // then I will send this % (lets say 5) to the seek function like:
        const x = (event.clientX * duration) / event.currentTarget.offsetWidth; // how to get sec?
        callback(x);
      }}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#ddd",
        borderRadius: 3,
        flex: 1,
        height: 6,
        overflow: "hidden",
        position: "relative"
      }}
    >
      <Progress progress={progress} />
    </div>
  );
};
```